# How can you change ident, which shows up as ident@hostname.com on ircll?

Tags: irc

I know the nickname and the real name field can be changed with environment variables such as IRCNICK and IRCNAME. However, the documentation does not tell you how the ident is changed. (The ident is the name that's used when you /whois nickname, and it shows up as part of **ident**@username.com in the host field, and the bolded part is what I'm trying to figure out how to change)

I'm wondering if this is possible on the ircll client.

Comment: Are you asking about cloaking? http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/IRC/Cloaks

Comment: @jasonwryan no, clocking is when you have a address like ident@hostname.com where hostname.com is the part where is changed so your ip/connection host gets clocked, I want to know how to change ident which comes before @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `IRCUSER`.

Comment: Looks like this worked, sad that this isn't documented anywhere in the man pages.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to the machine administrator. It's a system-level thing. IRC uses [RFC 1413](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident) to determine the identify of the connections it receives. The client has no control over it. (Except for some Windows clients that have an embedded ident server. That won't work on UNIX though, since you'd need `root` permissions to listen on the `ident` port.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your own server, you can install your own `identd` to spoof and say whatever you want. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question still comes up as first on Google search, I will add what works for me.

I am using Irrsi, when I am connected to the IRC server of my choice using `/connect`, next command I issue:

```
/set user_name myfavident
/save
```

Now I restart Irrsi and my `/whois` will show `myfavident@myip`.